# Removing HTML tags except line breaks

Tags: android, html, regex, line-breaks

I am receiving string from server having HTML tags. I am removing these tags using regular expression like `string1.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","")` but the problem is that it also remove line breaks and hyperlinks. I want to keep hyperlinks and line breaks and remove everything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use regexps for parsing HTML.

To strip it completely from HTML (not what you wanted, but simple to do):

```
String html = "<h1>I only want<br/>line breaks and " + 
    "<a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>links</a>, <i>not</i>" +
    " the <b>other</b> stuff";
String sansHtml = Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
```

To strip it selectively, retaining **only** `<a>` (and the `href` attribute) and `<br>` tags I suggest you use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/):

```
Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.none().addTags("a", "br").addAttributes("a", "href");
String jsoupHtml = Jsoup.clean(html, whitelist);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace the parts you want to keep by some intermediate format first and restore the original one after you removed all other tags.

```
string1.replaceAll("\\<br.*?>", "[br]");
string1.replaceAll("\\<a href='(.*?)'.*?>(.*?)\\<.*?>", "[link='$1' desc='$2']");
string1.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
string1.replaceAll("\\[br\\]", "<br\\>");
string1.replaceAll("\\[link='(.*?)' desc='(.*?)']", "<a href=\"$1\">$2<\\a>");
```

Code untested so it might not work :)

Comment: [This always feels relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) when people whips out regexps to deal with XML/HTML.

Comment: True, regex parsing will not work on every out-in-the-wild xml/html file. It will only work reliably if the file is of known syntax.